# Can I use the size of an array without having to place it in a variable

Tags: perl

Currently I am doing this to read the individual contents of an array

```
my $size = @words;
for(my $x = 0; $x < $size, $x++)
{
   print $words[$x]; 
}
```

Is there away to skip the $size assignment?  A way to cast the array and have one less line?

i.e.

```
for(my $x = 0; $x < $(@word), $x++)
{
   print $words[$x]; 
}
```

Can't seem to find the right syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`for` has a built in array iterator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) and `for` and `foreach` are synonyms.

```
for my $word (@words) {
    print $word;
}
```

This is the preferred way to iterate through arrays in Perl. C style 3 statement for-loops are discouraged unless necessary. They're harder to read and lead to bugs, like this one.

```
for(my $x = 0; $x < $size, $x++)
                         ^
             should be a ;
```

Comment: That last one can't fully develop into a bug because it's a syntax error. You'd have to use `,` instead of `;` both times (and then it'd fail `use strict`).

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $(@words), $i++) { ... $words[$i] ... }
```

with

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @words; $i++) { ... $words[$i] ... }
```

Just like in your assignment, an array evaluated in scalar context produces its size.

---

That said, using a C-style loop is complex and wasteful.

A better solution if you need the index:

```
for my $i (0..$#words) { ... $words[$i] ... }
```

A better solution if you don't need the index:

```
for my $word (@words) { ... $word ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Better to use `foreach`, but to your specific question, `@foo` in scalar context resolves to the length of the array, and `$#foo` resolves to the index of the last element:

```
foreach my $word (@words) { ... } # preferred

for(my $i = 0; $i < @words; ++$i) { my $word = $words[$i]; ... } # ok sometimes

for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#words; ++$i) { my $word = $words[$i]; ... } # same thing
```

(assuming that you haven't played with `$[`, which you shouldn't do.)

Comment: In Perl 5.30 playing with `$[` will [be an error](https://perldoc.pl/5.29.7/variables/$%5B).

Comment: @Grinnz yay! :)

Comment: Thjat should be `for my $i (0..$#words)`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that you are searching for is actually no syntax at all. If you use an array variable anywhere where Perl knows you should be using a scalar value (like as an operand to a comparison operator) then Perl gives you the number of elements in the array.

So, based on your example, this will work:

```
# Note: I've corrected a syntax error here.
# I replaced a comma with a semicolon
for (my $x = 0; $x < @words; $x++)
{
   print $words[$x]; 
}
```

But there are several ways that we can improve this. Firstly, let's get rid of the ugly and potentially confusing C-style `for` loop and replace it with a far easier to understand `foreach`.

```
foreach my $x (0 .. @words - 1)
{
   print $words[$x]; 
}
```

We can also improve on that `@words - 1`. Instead, we can use `$#words` which gives the final index in the array `@words`.

```
foreach my $x (0 .. $#words)
{
   print $words[$x]; 
}
```

Finally, we don't really need the index number here as we're just using it to access each element of the array in turn. Far better to iterate over the elements of the array rather than the indexes.

```
foreach my $element (@words)
{
   print $element; 
}
```

Comment: I meant the syntax as the proper way to cast an array into its size in the same line as the loop

Comment: @SergioD.Caplan: Right. And that's what I gave you right at the start of my answer.